# I'm trying to make a add remove input box with sortable jquery function to Sort the dynamically created input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/> ' + ($('.con div').length + 1) + '</div>');
  x.appendTo('#form .con')
});
  $("#minus").click(function(){
    x.remove


$("span").sortable({
  connectWith: ".con"
}).disableSelection();
```

SO my code can add delete but it cannot remove the added elemetns. I'm trying remove the desired boxes. Please help me out and heres the js fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/3eRHCDOkYW4lEXTzzGdx?p=preview

Comment: Well `x` is not in scope of your "minus " click method

Comment: What gets removed?  The last div added?  -> `$(".con div:last").remove();`

Comment: Hi @James its still not working. Could provide a js fiddle of that. I would really appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: [not a fiddle, it's a plnkr (?)](http://plnkr.co/edit/4P6HWu9jVTmZhOnEhMdb?p=info)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @James

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
$("div").remove("#form, .con");// used to be $("div").remove("#forn, .con");
```